# Find eigen value of 3x3 matrix whose $f_A(\lambda)=det(A-\lambda I_{3})=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Problem: Find the eigenvalue(s) of the matrix$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1&0\\0 & 0&1\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

I know that $f_A(\lambda)=det(A-\lambda I_{3})=0$

I assume the eigenvalue is zero. I know that I am wrong. How so?

Comment: Well, why do you assume the eigenvalues are $0$?

Comment: Why did you assume that $0$ is an eigenvalue?$$A-\lambda I_3=\begin{bmatrix}-\lambda&1&0\\0&-\lambda&0\\1&0&-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$$thus, $f_A(\lambda)=-\lambda^3+1$, thus the eigenvalues are the [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) of order 3.

Comment: To start with, note that $A$ preserves the norm $|v|^2 = |v_1|^2 + |v_2|^2 + |v_3|^2$, and thus in particular is invertible; that is, $\det A\not = 0$.

Comment: I assume that the eigenvalues are 0 as I assume the determinant of $A-\lambda I_3$ is 0. I used Sarrus's rule to find the determinant.

Comment: @Feona, in order to find eigenvalues we always require that $\text{det}(A-\lambda I_n)=0$ and then solving. It doesn't implies that $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue. By the way, $0$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $A$ is non invertible (you should try proving this claim). What is the determinant of $A-\lambda I_3$ according to your computation?

Comment: this matrix is an example of a permutation matrix. what that means is that components of $Px$ are a rearrangement of the  components of $x.$ this alone will tell you that absolute value of an eigenvalues must be one.

Answer (score 1):

Do as you say you know and assume nothing, in particular don't assume something wrong:

$$\det(\lambda I-A)=\begin{vmatrix}\lambda&\!-1&0\\0&\lambda&\!-1\\\!-1&0&\lambda\end{vmatrix}=\lambda^3-1=(\lambda-1)(\lambda^2+\lambda+1)$$

and you get

$$\det(\lambda I-A)=0\iff \lambda=1,\,\frac{-1\pm\sqrt3\,i}2$$

Answer (score 0):

Denote
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1&0\\0 & 0&1\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Well, the sum of all the rows is equal to $1$, thus 
$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$ is the eigen-vector for $\lambda_1=1$

Next, we know that
$$det(M)=\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3$$
And
$$trace(M)=\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3$$

If we swap row 1 and row 2 of $M$ and then row 2 and row 3, we get $I$, thus
$$det(M)=--det(I)=1$$
All you have left is to solve
$$
\lambda_1=1
$$$$
\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3=1
$$$$
\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

@Joanpemo has provided the solution. Here is verification:

[image: Mathematica solution]